# What's the raised part of an arch called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What's that embossed or raised part of an arc or arch called? I am looking for the upper part of the shape, which is kind of raised and forms a mini circle.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean an arc like the geometric shape? Or an *arch*, like the Arc de Triomphe?

Comment: IF you mean an arch, you may be referring to the [keystone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_%28architecture%29).  However, any embossment would be purely decorative and not an integral part of the keystone.

Comment: You mean the arched part of the arch?

Comment: @ThePhoton- Yea, but only the upper side of it. Not the whole curve.

Comment: I think this question can safely be labeled Noah's Arc :))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't see a "circular" bit at the top of the arch in the OP's picture.

The parts of the arch are:

- The absolute top of the arch is the [apex](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apex).
- The curve at the *top* of the arch is known as the [***crown***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crown).
- The point at which the curve begins is the [springing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/springing#Noun) or spring-line.
- The curve between the springing and the crown is known as the [haunch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haunch).
- The inner curve of the arch is the [intrados](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intrados).
- The outer curve is the [extrados](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extrados).
- The arch itself is made of sections called [voussoirs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voussoir). So the crown and the haunch are made of a number of voussoirs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *[ogive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogive)*, of which wikipedia says:

> An ogive (/ˈoʊdʒaɪv/OH-jyv) is the roundly tapered end of a two-dimensional or three-dimensional object.

Later, the wikipedia [article on ogives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogive) distinguishes between "spitzer ogives" and "elliptical ogives". A Gothic arch typically is a spitzer ogive, while the [Gateway Arch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_Arch) illustrated in the question is a "weighted or flattened" catenary arch.  A *[catenary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary)*, wikipedia says, is "superficially similar in appearance to a parabola (though mathematically quite different)".  At certain magnifications, portions of parabolas, ellipses, and catenaries look much alike, and I think the top of the Gateway Arch looks a lot like an elliptical ogive.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ogive) lists several senses of *ogive*, including "A Gothic pointed arch, or a rib of a Gothic vault" and "(ballistics) The pointed, curved nose of a bullet, missile, or rocket".

You may also find terms like the following of interest:  [archivolt (or voussure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivolt), "an ornamental molding or band following the curve on the underside of an arch"; *[spandrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandrel)*;  *[intrados](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intrados)*, "inner curve of an arch or vault"; *[voussoir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voussoir)*, "a wedge-shaped element, typically a stone, used in building an arch or vault".  See nomenclature in first diagram in wikipedia [arch article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch).